# Dropdown menu not showing in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm trying to get [a basic dropdown menu](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns) in Bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <!-- Link or button to toggle dropdown -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

However, nothing shows up. I know the local CSS and JS files are being referred correctly. As far as I understand, the default JS includes all the plugins.

EDIT: Thanks to all for your feedback. I can only add, in case people find themselves in the same situation I am, to move [further down](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups) in the tutorial before copying and pasting the snippets.

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'd never used jsfiddle before, so I'm not sure if everything is OK, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YNguG/) it is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think your code was basically good, but you are missing a link to trigger the drop down. See ths   [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/Xag9Y/)

Note that I added

```
<a id="drop1" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

Here's an example of how to include it in a [complete nav bar](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/2bXmT/)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot... It's a frustrating enterprise trying to learn Bootstrap. I would expect official snippets to be self-contained but, alas, I guess they expect you to know what you're doing. Any advice on how to acquire the minimal HTML/CSS/JS knowledge in order to properly harness Bootstrap will be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: I know what you mean about use of the snippets not always being as simple as you might expect. I've found myself inspecting a lot of HTML and CSS source code to fill in the blanks. I'm starting to appreciate the logic behind how the styling and scaffolding work though so it's all getting easier with time ;)

Answer (score 4):

Please pay extra attention to comment `<-- Link or button to toggle dropdown -->` in you code. You need to put a Link or button with data-toggle="dropdown" property to activate the Dropdown.

Try this :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <!-- Link or button to toggle dropdown -->

  <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <i class="icon-user"></i> TestDropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <i class="icon-user"></i> TestDropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown Test </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a clear example. It taught me that several buttons/links can trigger the same dropdown, as well as some idiosyncrasies about Bootstrap docs!

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns):

> Looking at just the dropdown menu, here's the required HTML. You need to wrap the dropdown's trigger and the dropdown menu within .dropdown, or another element that declares position: relative;. Then just create the menu.

So you probably need to set the CSS for your `dropdown` class to have (at least) `position: relative;`. Also you have a `display:none` on `.dropdown-menu` by default. Try also overriding that.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe the provided example does the required .dropdown wrapping, no?

Comment: Well there is no `.dropdown` class in default bootstrap css, so you have to do that.

Comment: Thanks again, but this doesn't fix it. In any case, my (unminified) `bootstrap.css` has, spread between lines 2840 and 2843, the declaration `.dropup, .dropdown { position: relative; }`. I added your suggestion manually, to no avail.

Comment: You have a `display:none` on `.dropdown-menu` by default. Try overriding that.

Comment: Thanks again, Miha. I think [a few sections down](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups) there is a fuller example of how dropdowns are meant to be used. I know I've been a grumpy old man, but... this piecemeal approach is disconcerting when applied to a technical product. I guess one is supposed to read all the docs before trying the stuff. Further, my CSS knowledge is well behind yours, but precisely I was hoping a *very* rough understanding of CSS would allow me to use Bootstrap *instead* of tweaking the CSS itself! Oh, well... Thanks once more!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of div,try a parent ul and li to wrap your ul that you have posted above.
for example,

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills span7 pull-right" id="upper_username_hide">
       <li class= "dropdown" data-dropdown="dropdown">
         <a id="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <b class="caret dropdown-toggle"></b>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I dont think tab-index will be necessary as bootstrap css takes care of that.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! At the risk of throwing around many open-ended questions in comments... How do you go about building your understanding of Bootstrap usage? Any recommended resources besides the official documentation? (The tabindex settings were copied verbatim from the official snippet.)

Comment: Creating and experimenting with the bootstrap classes is always the best way for this,but when you're at a loss,try inspecting code from some existing sites already using twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I discovered the `.dropdown-menu` bootstrap class had set the top property to:`top: 100%`, that caused that the dropdown was shown outside the viewport.  I did override the top value with another class and now is working.